# PHP image transparent

Tags: php, image, resize, thumbnails, transparent

I'm trying to resize a PNG transparent image using the following code:

```
$src=ImageCreateFrompng($uploadedfile);
$background=imagecolorallocate($src,0,0,0);
imagecolortransparent($src,$background);
imagealphablending($src,false);
imagesavealpha($src,true);
$dst=ImageCreateTrueColor($tn_width,$tn_height);
imagecopyresampled($dst,$src,0,0,0,0,$tn_width,$tn_height,$width,$height);
Imagepng($dst,$dstfile);
```

I used `imagealphablending($src,false)` and `imagesavealpha($src,true)` but it still uploads an image with a black background instead of a transparent one.

Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you copy transparent image on a black one. Your false setting for aplhablending only applyes to original image, so when you copy on new image, aplha blending is turned on.
Your code needs just a little improvement:

```
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($dst, 0,0,0,127);  //Transparent background color
imagealphablending($dst,false);            //Not to compound transparent colors with opaque
imagesavealpha($dst,true);                 //Allow transparency
imagefilledrectangle($dst, 0, 0, imagesx($dst), imagesy($dst), $transparent);   //Give the destination image transparent background
//Now you can copy
```

### OR JUST

```
imagealphablending($dst,false);   //I'm not 100% sure this will make it, but its worth a try
```

Comment: What should I do to fix it?

Comment: I've improved my post slightly. Sorry for posting it so short the first time :)

Comment: Just a little error: imagecolorallocatealpha instead of imagecollorallocatealpha... It works!!

Comment: Oh, sorry for typo errors. Feel free to sugest edits for posts that contains errors.

Comment: I'm not sure which code do you tapl about, but if you was replying to my not about sugesting edits, make sure to read [Stackoverflow:About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page

Answer (score 0):

imagecolorallocate($src,0,0,0);

That line looks like it gets the image from the source, then uses a 000 background. Which would be black. Just a guess, not familiar with the function